# Remove tzsp headers to normalize pacquet

Tags: python, scapy

im trying to create a little sniffer on `python, to remove the tzsp encapulation that my router uses to send me 
a copy all all the packet that flows through it. The problem is that i want to use ossim, and snort to analyze
the traffic, and woul like to de-encapsulate the packet and send it to a virtual interface where snort is
listening.

I allready have the sniffer, but didnt find the way to strip the tzsp headers to get the original packet and
send it after. I see that other people have done this on perl, but dont know how to do the same on scapy.

Its basically remove the firts 5 bytes.

# --- Cut TZSP bytes
   my $tzspheader = substr $udp->{data}, 0, 5;
   my $tzspdata = substr $udp->{data}, 5;

Full perl script -> http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Calea_perl_trafr

Can i use the pkt scapy format as an array ? If i remove the headers the packet will be as received by
the router, can i use scapy to sned it directly or do i have to create a emtpy packet according to the original
packet protocol and copy each field to the new one ?

Thank you All